# Dates and scopes are inconsistent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, datetime, activerecord, scope

I have the following scope:

```
scope :this_month, :conditions => ["created_at >= ?", Date.today.beginning_of_month]
```

Which makes the SQL output of `a.response_sets.this_month.to_sql`:

```
SELECT "response_sets".* FROM "response_sets" WHERE created_at >= '2012-05-01'
```

But since today is actually June 1, that date seems wrong. So, I tried bypassing the scope and just doing a condition directly, like so:

```
a.response_sets.where(["created_at >= ?", Date.today.beginning_of_month]).to_sql
```

Which then, outputs:

```
SELECT "response_sets".* FROM "response_sets" WHERE created_at >= '2012-06-01'
```

Which is correct. So why is there a difference between doing `Date.today.beginning_of_month` in a scope and doing it directly in `where`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When working with dates in scopes you should use a lambda so the scope gets evaluated every time it is called:

```
scope :this_month, -> { where("created_at >= ?", Date.today.beginning_of_month) }
```